# Skip the control while find using data attribute of parent control

Tags: jquery, html

I have couple of check boxes and I have to find the checked check boxes but I need to skip those which has 'Unknown' as data attribute of check box's parent control(span). I cannot add data attribute to check box because of some other limitations.

### HTML code

```
<ul>
    <li class="race">
        <span Caption="Other" data-originalName="A">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Chk1" onclick="Selection();" />
        <label for="Chk1">A</label>
    </li>
    <li class="race">
        <span Caption="Other" data-originalName="B">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Chk2" onclick="Selection();"/>
        <label for="Chk2">B</label>
    </li>
    <li class="race">
        <span Caption="Other" data-originalName="C">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Chk3" onclick="Selection();"/>
        <label for="Chk3">C</label>
    </li>
    <li class="race">
        <span Caption="Other" data-originalName="D">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Chk4" onclick="Selection();"/>
        <label for="Chk4">D</label>
    </li>
    <li class="race">
        <span Caption="Other" data-originalName="Unknown">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Chk5" onclick="Selection();"/>
        <label for="Chk5">Unknown</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### jQuery code

```
var arrSelectedRaces=$(".race").find("input[type=checkbox]:not(:parent[data-originalName='Unknown']):checked")
```

What I am missing in jQuery script?

Comment: Can you add more code, like the html where the checkboxes are?

Comment: @depperm Just now added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.filter()`.

In the function passed to `.filter()`, we check if the closest span (the parent) has a `data-originalName` attribute of 'Unknown'. If so, return true otherwise return false.

```
$('.race').find('input:checkbox').filter(function(){
    return $(this).closest('span').attr('data-originalName') != 'Unknown';
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/60hjzu6s/)